# insertion sort > problems with immutable values in arrays passed by reference

Tags: c++, arrays, swift, sorting

having a problem with swift arrays passed by reference not unwrapping correctly during a nested loop in an insertion sort.

//-- C++ WORKS --

//In C++ this function is tested and works correctly:

```
struct moveRecord
{
    int fromSquare;
    int toSquare;
    int capturedPiece;
    int moveScore;
};

struct moveRecord m1 = {20, 28, 4, 0};
struct moveRecord m2 = {20, 29, 5, 0};
struct moveRecord m3 = {20, 30, 1, 0};
struct moveRecord m4 = {20, 31, 2, 0};
struct moveRecord m5 = {20, 32, 3, 0};
moves[0] = m1;
moves[1] = m2;
moves[2] = m3;
moves[3] = m4;
moves[4] = m5;

movesStr = moves2Str( moves, numMoves );
cout << "UNSORTED: " << movesStr << endl;

sortMoves( moves, numLegalMoves );

movesStr = moves2Str( moves, numMoves );
cout << "SORTED: " << movesStr << endl;


void sortMoves( moveRecord moves[], int numMoves )
{
    int i, j;
    struct moveRecord tempMove;

    for (j=1; j<numMoves; j++) {
        cout << "j=" << j << " of " << numMoves << endl;
        tempMove = moves[j];
        for (i=j-1; i>-1; i--) {
            cout << "  i=" << i << endl;
            // need to compare abs() values, or else black & white get sorted differently
            if ( abs(moves[i].capturedPiece) >= abs(tempMove.capturedPiece) ) {cout << "break" << endl; break;}
            moves[i+1] = moves[i];
            }
            cout << "we are out of iLoop" << endl;
        moves[i+1] = tempMove;
        }
    return;
}
```

with the following results in the XCode log:

```
UNSORTED: e4.4 f4.5 g4.1 h4.2 a5.3
j=1 of 5
  i=0
we are out of iLoop
j=2 of 5
  i=1
break
we are out of iLoop
j=3 of 5
  i=2
  i=1
break
we are out of iLoop
j=4 of 5
  i=3
  i=2
  i=1
break
we are out of iLoop
SORTED:  f4.5 e4.4 a5.3 h4.2 g4.1
```

the array elements sort from: .4 .5 .1 .2 .3
to the correct sequence: .5 .4 .3 .2 .1
great! C++ is doing the right thing.

//-- SWIFT RESULTS DIFFER --

```
func sortMoves( theMoves: inout [moveRecord])
{
    var i : Int = 0
    var j : Int = 0
    var tempMove : moveRecord
    let numMoves : Int = theMoves.count

    for j in 1..<numMoves {
        print("j=\(j) of \(numMoves)")
        tempMove = theMoves[j]
        for i in stride(from:j-1, through:0, by:-1) {
            print("  i=\(i)")
            // need to compare abs() values or black/white sort differently
            if ( abs(theMoves[i].capturedPiece!) >= abs(tempMove.capturedPiece!) ) {print("break"); break}
            theMoves[i+1] = theMoves[i]
            }
        print("we are out of iLoop")
        theMoves[i+1] = tempMove
        }

    return
}
```

with the following results in the XCode log:

```
Unsorted Moves: f4.4  g4.5  h4.1  a5.2  b5.3
j=1 of 5
  i=0
we are out of iLoop
j=2 of 5
  i=1
break
we are out of iLoop
j=3 of 5
  i=2
  i=1
  i=0
break
we are out of iLoop
j=4 of 5
  i=3
  i=2
  i=1
  i=0
break
we are out of iLoop
Sorted Moves: f4.4  b5.3  a5.2  h4.1  h4.1
```

so the array elements sort from: .4 .5 .1 .2 .3
to the WRONG sequence: .4 .3 .2 .1 .1

the code is semantically identical to the working C++ code,
yet — the first entry doesnt sort, the last is repeated, 
and the high move is LOST.  :-(

seeing how in C++ log we get: J=3, i=1 > break

and in swift log it goes: J=3, i=1.. i=0 > break

leads me to think the problem is with the way swift is unwrapping array values passed by reference when being compared in the IF condition.

an hour of research reveals that:

```
| By default, array parameters are immutable 
| within the called function. To modify the copy 
| of the array that is passed to insertionSort, add
| var before toSort in the function header (Swift 1.2)
```

this changes is Swift 3: 
    | In Swift 3 prefix the return type with inout [DONE]

so my question is the error here in swift unwrapping: moves[i].capturedPiece!
when doing the:  IF (moves![i] >= tempMove) {break} ??

i cant see the way to get the same functionality out of swift that can be achived in C++

anyone have any suggestions for getting insertion sort with array passed by reference in SWIFT 3!?!?

john penner (toronto island)

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is unrelated to passing arrays by reference, value types
or unwrapping. The real problem is that in Swift, a

```
for <variable> in <sequence> { ... }
```

statement defines a variable which is valid only in the scope of the loop, possibly hiding a variable with the same name in the outer scope.
You cannot refer to the "last value" of the variable after the
loop statement (which you can in C).

In your case,

```
for i in stride(from:j-1, through:0, by:-1) { ... }
```

defines a variable `i` for the scope of the loop body, hiding the outer variable `i` defined at the top of the function. Therefore in

```
theMoves[i+1] = tempMove
```

`i` is always zero, because that variable was never changed.

Actually the compiler warns you about the problem:

```
var i : Int = 0
// variable 'i' was never mutated; consider changing to 'let' constant

var j : Int = 0
// warning: initialization of variable 'j' was never used; consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it
```

A correct version of your code with slight simplifications would be

```
func sortMoves( theMoves: inout [moveRecord])
{
    for j in 1..<theMoves.count {
        let tempMove = theMoves[j]
        var i = j-1
        while i >= 0 && abs(theMoves[i].capturedPiece!) < abs(tempMove.capturedPiece!) {
            theMoves[i+1] = theMoves[i]
            i -= 1
        }
        theMoves[i+1] = tempMove
    }
}
```

Comment: brilliant! thank you martin — the compiler was already warning that i was never mutated — i should have seen that, but coming from C++, i didnt expect the hiding of _i_ locally within the scope of a loop.